# Stop CkEditor from adding styles

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I don't want my user to have any control over styles, but in the [CkEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), it automatically adds a style attribute to the `p` tag if you copy and past from word or text edit. For instants, it might make `<p style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px">text</p>` when all I want it to make is `<p></p>` How do I fix this? As in, how do i limit the tags CkEditor can make or prevent it from adding certain styles?

Comment: Then just use `textarea` without any plugins

Comment: @MiqdadAli I need their to be options for italics, automatic p tag creation, bold, underline, and full screen editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you can only use features like [config.forcePasteAsPlainText](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-forcePasteAsPlainText). When you set this option to `true` only paragraphs and line breaks will be created when pasting (as for plain text).

In CKEditor 4.1, which will be released in February, new important feature will be introduced - [data and features activation based on configuration](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9829). You'll be able to configure which elements, styles, attributes and classes are allowed.